# How to make this code better for checking null condition

Tags: jquery

In case if i recieve a null value from the backend response i want to substitute 'NA' for that corresponding value

I have done this , its working , but want to know if there is any better way of doing this .

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: yql,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            var DaysLow = data.query.results.quote.DaysLow;
            var DaysHigh = data.query.results.quote.DaysHigh;
            var ChangeinPercent = data.query.results.quote.ChangeinPercent;
            var Name = data.query.results.quote.Name;
            var LastTradeTime = data.query.results.quote.LastTradeTime;
            var LastTradePriceOnly = data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
            var Change = data.query.results.quote.Change;
            if (!DaysHigh)
            {
                DaysHigh = 'NA';
            }
            if (!ChangeinPercent)
            {
                ChangeinPercent = 'NA';
            }
            if (!Name)
            {
                Name = 'NA';
            }
            if (!LastTradeTime)
            {
                LastTradeTime = 'NA';
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The short-circuiting `||` operator may help you, assuming you also want to substitute the values of empty strings, not just `null` ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var DaysLow = data.query.results.quote.DaysLow || "NA"`

and so on...

or even put your default value in a variable and use it,

e.g.

```
var DEFAULT = "NA"
var DaysLow = data.query.results.quote.DaysLow || DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

A little trickier, but it helps you to declare once the name of properties you want (good for future maintenance)...

```
//avoid undefined errors
var quote = data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.quote;

var interestingProperties = ['DaysLow', 'DaysHigh', 
    'ChangeinPercent', 'Name', 'LastTradeTime', 'LastTradePriceOnly', 'Change'];

var myObject = {};
$.each(interestingProperties, function(index, prop){
    myObject[prop] = quote[prop] || "NA";
})
```

Comment: i dont see how this helps with future 'maintenance', you still are having to declare the properties that you are wanting to default.  This is just an over engineered way of doing whats in the OP.

Comment: I would say that if you need to add or modify a property - i.e. if ajax response changes - you do not need to copy/paste rows or words, just add a element to the array.

Answer (score -1):

Good practices when writing JS code: declare all your varibles at the top of the scope, you can use one "var" key word for that.
They will be moved there anyway thanks to **variables hoisting**